# Differences on those two PHP statements

Tags: php, wordpress

I see both are very often being used, of course not only for `get_post_type` also any other functions.

```
<php if (get_post_type() == 'post') {} ?>
<php if ('post' == get_post_type()) {} ?>
```

What is the real difference? Is it just readability, or also performance?

Comment: None. It's not even a [Yoda condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), it's simply reversed.

Comment: @deceze, I thought it was a Yoda Condition, they're just reversed - It's the first example in your link.

Comment: @thePav Yoda conditions are done to avoid accidental assignment. In this case, you couldn't assign anything to either side in the first place.

Comment: @deceze, yep that makes sense - the wiki page may need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements will function the same.  Performance unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

No Difference here..!! In your case both statement will work same because you are comparing them. Result may be different if you will try to assign values to any variable in spite of compare.